# Retrieve list of items from table which has max count

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables `Distributor` and `Reseller`, and the have columns like

**Distributor**

```
  id, name
```

**Reseller**

```
 Id name ChildDistriid
```

I want to select details of distributor who have maximum Reseller.

This is my code so far:

```
alter procedure sp
as
begin
    with CTE_RN as
    (
        select 
            d.name as Distributor,
            r.name as Reseller,
            count(r.childdistributorid) over (partition by r.childdistributorid) as Rcount 
        from 
            distributor d
        join 
            reseller r on r.childdistributorid = d.id 
        group by 
            d.name, r.name, r.childdistributorid 
    )
    select * 
    from CTE_RN  
    group by Distributor, Reseller 
    having Rcount = max(Rcount)
end

exec sp
```

Comment: Now what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alter procedure sp
as

```
begin

with CTE_RN as
(
select d.name as Distributor,r.name as Reseller,count(r.childdistributorid) over (partition by r.childdistributorid) as Rcount from distributor d
join reseller r on r.childdistributorid=d.id group by 
d.name,r.name,r.childdistributorid 
)
select * from CTE_RN  where Rcount=(select max(Rcount) from CTE_RN )
end
exec sp
```

Answer (score 2):

If am not wrong you need this

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties *
FROM   (SELECT d.name                                 AS Distributor,
               r.name                                 AS Reseller,
               Count(r.childdistributorid)OVER (partition BY r.childdistributorid) AS Rcount
        FROM   distributor d
               JOIN reseller r
                 ON r.childdistributorid = d.id) a
ORDER  BY Rcount DESC
```